# Vue.js - custom photo grid with custom overlay

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, bootstrap-vue

how can i make a photos grid (each photo is a card) with custom overlay.
when the user hover the photo, he will see the details overlay.
so the user will see the photo and details on it.

i tried to do this with "Beautify" and "Bootstrap-Vue"
and did not succeed.

example for what i look for: [example website](https://nomadlist.com/)

Comment: Try HTML, CSS and JavaScript for that

Comment: could you provide your tried work

Answer (score 1):

Just build your grid of items - styling them with bootstrap "Card" component and grid system to make it as a grid.

Then just use this custom vue component with `v-for` and then bind `@mouseover` + `@mouseleave` on this element to change the state of hovered property or whatever you like to call it. Then just change your text or structure in your component according to hovered state.

Simple demo here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/e8y0hLps/

Comment: thanks!
the v-if is very useful but i want to add the details over the card,
and not switch the element.

there is a "Vue" way to do that and not with Css?